# Reading file line by line from windows bat file

Tags: batch-file, readfile

I am trying to read a file line by line from .bat file.

```
@echo off
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in  (instance2.txt) do (
 echo %%A
 set line=%%A
 echo %line%
)

echo ******end******
```

The problem is that every time it is printing the last line only.
please help me sort out the problem.
Thanx in advance.

Amit.

Answer (score 0):

you need a [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%A in  (instance2.txt) do (
 echo %%A
 set "line=%%A"
 echo !line!
)

echo ******end******
```